# addEventListener in useEffect use function before event happen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some Menu with links and button that open and close this menu. I want made some functionality that help me to close this menu if I click on other elements on website not even this button which close it.

> This code are close my menu after component was mount and after this button didn't work at all.

```
// state with menu status (open or hide)
const [menuStatus, setMenuStatus] = useState(false);

// function that change the state
const toggleMenuHandler = () => {
    setMenuStatus((menuStatus) => !menuStatus);
};

// there is problem. I want that this function (toggleMenuHandler)
// will activate only after menu is opened.
// but react run this function as soon as component was mount.
useEffect(() => {

    // if menu is open I want create a window.listener that 
    // help me close this menu if I click somewhere else not only toggle button.

    if (menuStatus) {
      window.addEventListener("click", toggleMenuHandler);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("click", toggleMenuHandler);
      };
    }
  }, [menuStatus]);

  return(
      <div className="menu">
          <button
              onClick={toggleMenuHandler}
          >
              Open Menu
          </button>

          <div className={menuStatus ? "menu__window" : "menu__disabled"}>
              <h3>Menu Window</h3>
              
              <Link to="/">Home page</Link>
              <Link to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>
              <Link to="/prices">Prices</Link>
              <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
              <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
```

There's picture that showing my problem. I want close this menu window by click on no matter what element was clicked. Not only toggle button but by whole elements on website.

[image: Example of menu that I have]

Comment: `if (menuStatus) {` doesn't work?

Comment: @Konrad if menuStatus true (it's mean if menu open) I want create window click listener if menu open then create click listener that closes menu if I click anyone element on website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
const toggleMenuHandler = () => {
    setMenuStatus((menuStatus) => !menuStatus);
};
```

to

```
const toggleMenuHandler = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setMenuStatus((menuStatus) => !menuStatus);
};
```

Comment: I knew the answer will be so simple.. Sorry for your time sir. Thank you so much!